# Achar dia da semana do primeiro dia de janeiro a partir da data da páscoa

Tags: c

Tenho um trabalho de faculdade em que eu devo construir um calendário em C a partir da data da páscoa de um determinado ano. Consigo achar a data da páscoa e construir corretamente o calendário em arte ASCII, mas não consigo achar o dia da semana do 1º de Janeiro.

[Nesta página da Wikipédia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week)(em inglês) está escrito:

> A aproximação básica de todos os métodos consiste em achar uma 'data âncora': um par conhecido(por exemplo: 1º de Janeiro de 1800, um quarta-feira), determinar a quantidade de dias entre a data âncora e a data que você quer encontrar, e usar o módulo 7 (% 7 ou mod 7) para achar o código do novo dia da semana.

Decidi então aplicar esse conceito em meu programa, o snippet ficou assim:

```
if(mes_pascoa == 3)
    dia_semana = (dia_pascoa + bissexto + 28 + 31) % 7;
else if(mes_pascoa == 4)
    dia_semana = (dia_pascoa + bissexto + 31 + 28 + 31) % 7;
```

Porém o valor do dia da semana está incorreto, mesmo com a implementação correta do código. Por exemplo, para `mes_pascoa = 3` e `dia_pascoa = 31` que foi a páscoa do ano de 2013 portanto `bissexto = 0`, o valor de `dia_semana` deve ser 2, já que o 1º de Janeiro de 2013 caiu em uma terça-feira. Porém, meu snippet está retornando 6 para `dia_semana`.

Minha pergunta é, existe algum erro em meu código ou neste conceito que eu utilizei? Adoraria saber também se existe alguma outra implementação de código em C que possa me ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que esse conceito na própria página da Wikipédia está incorreto ou foi mal-interpretado por mim, mas descobri uma solução que me serve muito bem:

Para chegar ao 1º de Janeiro a partir de qualquer data, deve-se calcular o número de dias entre as duas datas e fazer o módulo 7. O resultado dará o dia do primeiro domingo do mês. Devemos subtrair este resultado de 8 para obtermos o dia da semana do 1º de Janeiro. Por exemplo:

> Para 2013, a distância entre a data da páscoa (31/3) e o 1º de Janeiro é de 90 dias. O módulo de 90 por 7 é 6 (portanto, 6/1 foi um domingo). Devemos agora voltar 5 unidades dos 7 "códigos" de dia da semana possíveis (com 0 sendo domingo no 1º de Janeiro e 7 sendo o domingo depois da primeira semana do mês), ou 6 dias dos 8 disponíveis entre a primeira e a segunda semana. Com isso, obtemos o código 2, que representa a terça-feira.

Em código pode ser representado da seguinte maneira:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* Descobridor de 1º de Janeiro a partir da data da páscoa */
typedef struct{
    int dia, mes, ano, cod_semana;
} Data;

Data dia_janeiro(Data data){
    Data d; 
    int ano = data.ano, bissexto = 0;
    while(ano % 100 == 0)
        ano /= 100;
    if(ano % 4 == 0)
        bissexto = 1;

    d.dia = 1;
    d.mes = 1;
    d.ano = data.ano;

    if(data.mes == 3)
        d.cod_semana = 8 - ((data.dia + 28 + 31 + bissexto) % 7);
    else if(data.mes == 4)
        d.cod_semana = 8 - ((data.dia + 31 + 28 + 31 + bissexto) % 7);
    if(d.cod_semana > 6) d.cod_semana -= 7;
    return d;
}

int main(){
    Data pascoa;
    pascoa.dia = 31;
    pascoa.mes = 3;
    pascoa.ano = 2013;
    printf("Código do 1º de Janeiro: %d.\n", dia_janeiro(pascoa).cod_semana);
    return 0;
}
```

Troque `pascoa.dia`, `pascoa.mes` e `pascoa.ano` por quaisquer valores válidos de uma data da páscoa e você terá o dia da semana em código do 1º de Janeiro do respectivo ano.

Answer (score 1):

As somas devem ser subtraccoes. Se a partir dum Domingo de Pascoa queres "andar para tras", para o 1º de Janeiro ... subtrai!

```
if(mes_pascoa == 3)
    dia_semana = (dia_pascoa - bissexto - 28 - 31) % 7;
else if(mes_pascoa == 4)
    dia_semana = (dia_pascoa - bissexto - 31 - 28 - 31) % 7;
```

Algumas implementacoes fazem modulos 'estranhos' quando ha numeros negativos. Eu somava um valor grande suficiente ao calculo para evitar numeros negativos.

```
if(mes_pascoa == 3)
    dia_semana = ((dia_pascoa - bissexto - 28 - 31) + 700) % 7;
else if(mes_pascoa == 4)
    dia_semana = ((dia_pascoa - bissexto - 31 - 28 - 31) + 700) % 7;
```

Comment: Estava com dúvida nisso, mesmo para calcular a 'distância' entre duas datas, pode ser aplicado o conceito de progresso e retrocesso? Isso não iria me dar uma contagem de dias negativa no caso de retrocesso?

Comment: Sim, vai dar data negativa. Eu nao tenho problema nenhum com data negativa ... 0 de Abril de 2015 corresponde a 31 de Marco ... -4 de Maio de 2015 corresponde a 26 de Abril

Comment: Ainda assim o 1º de Janeiro não está correto, para o ano de 2013 ele cai num domingo. Estou começando a achar que o problema está no conceito...

Comment: `31 - 0 - 28 - 31` dá -28, e `700 - 28` dá 672. 672 % 7 é 0. E `31 % 7` é 3

Comment: Tens que tirar os dias do mes corrente. Para 20 de Abril (2014), a conta é `20 - 20 - 0 - 31 - 28 - 31 + 1`

Answer (score 1):

E que tal ignorar a Pascoa e usar a biblioteca do C?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *ds[] = {"Domingo", "Segunda", "Terca",
                        "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sabado"};
    struct tm tm = {0};
    tm.tm_mday = 1;
    tm.tm_mon = 0; // Janeiro
    tm.tm_year = 113; // 2013
    tm.tm_isdst = 0;
    mktime(&tm); // normalizar tm
    printf("1 de Janeiro de %d calhou em %s.\n",
          tm.tm_year + 1900, ds[tm.tm_wday]);
    return 0;
}
```

Podes ver o [codigo a funcionar no ideone](http://ideone.com/9vW5dN).

Comment: Adoraria usar outras bibliotecas @pmg, mas o trabalho diz que deve-se montar o calendário a partir da data da páscoa.